# Making constructor in C++ with initializing vector

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, initialization

In my header file:

```
class Recursion
{
private:

    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>> _vector3;
    std::string go_on(int prev, int now);

    // function 2
public:
    // function 3
};
```

I was trying to write a constructor for _vector3 and initialize it, but it keeps printing error.

```
Recursion::Recursion()
{
    _vector3.clear(); 
}

std::string Recursion::go_on(int prev, int now)
{
    // ...
}
```

Error message here:

```
src/recursion.cpp:7:14: error: definition of implicitly-declared ‘constexpr Recursion::Recursion()’
    7 | Recursion::Recursion()
      |              ^
```

Error message when there is no constructor:

```
In file included from src/main.cpp:1:
src/reecursion.h: In constructor ‘constexpr Recursion::Recursion()’:
src/recursion.h:7:7: warning: ‘Recursion::_vector3’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
    7 | class Recursion
      |       ^~~~~
src/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
src/main.cpp:7:11: note: synthesized method ‘constexpr Recursion::Recursion()’ first required here
    7 |     Recursion recursion;
      |
```

Comment: At this time class `Recursion` does not declare a constructor, so there would be an error if you implemented one.. Side note. A `vector` is default constructed empty, so in a default constructor for `Recursion` there is no need to `clear` the `vector`.

Comment: Thank you. Proves my guess above correct. In the definition of `Recursion`, probably in the `public:` area, you need to add `Recursion();` to tell the compiler to expect a definition of the constructor will be forthcoming in the code.

Comment: I edited my question with error message. Can you please check it one more time?

Comment: `Recursion::Recursion()
{
    _vector3.clear(); 
}` looks weird. Presumably `vector3` is a member variable, so it is already empty when your object is constructed - what's the point of `.clear()`ing it in the constructor?

Comment: You can't just implement the constructor without declaring it first, in the body of the class. Note how you've mentioned `go_on` in two places - a declaration (without the body) and a definition. You need to do the same with the constructor. That said, you don't really need the constructor - at least, not the one you've shown, it does nothing useful.

Comment: The EffectiveC Warning is telling you to do something unnecessary, but will help clarify things for readers of your code. What it is recommending is like this: https://godbolt.org/z/srKf4z686 It is now clear that nothing special is required in the initialization of  `_vector3`.

Comment: Maybe I had some misunderstandings. Thank you for answering!

Comment: This question would have been easier to understand if you had provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). An MRE is a _complete_ program, with `#include` directives and anything else needed to push it through the compiler. When you provide an MRE, then we can copy it, and reproduce your error on our own computers.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing information, tbxfreeware. Have a nice day!

Comment: Side note: Those warnings are a distillation of the recommendations in Scott Meyers's book Effective C++. Some of the recommendations no longer apply (and some of that's because subsequent revisions to the language fixed a lot of the stuff he pointed out), but it is still a good book to read. His newer book Effective Modern C++  is more appropriate today.

Comment: Here is some reading on the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), something so useful that it's something that should be taught almost immediately in any C++ course. But [for some reason](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) it's rarely covered at all.

Comment: Thank you user4581301 for helping me a lot!